# Creating Instance Of Class Based On ClassName : string

Tags: typescript, angular, typescript1.8

Before anyone marks this as duplicate please read below,

My scenario doesn't just involve TypeScript but also **Angular2.**

**Objective**

I need a method in app.component.ts which takes a string(Class Name) and creates a instance of that. The classes exist in other ts files.

**Now to the use case:**
I have a method `getWidgetObjectFromClassName(className : string) : Object{}`  which needs to return the instances of the class name which is in string format.
Now the problem,

I tried using NameSpace and doing `let instance = new SampleNS['OtherName']();` (SampleNS is a namespace), works perfectly fine in the case of single file.

**But Now**
 i have multiple ts files lets say interfaces.ts, classes.ts, otherclasses.ts. Im using `export namespace SampleNS{}` in interface.ts all works, next in classes.ts using the `/// <reference path="interfaces.ts" />` and same namespace `SampleNS`.

Now my method `getWidgetObjectFromClassName(className : string) : Object{}` is in xyz.ts, and now which import should i give?, my point being if i say `import {SampleNS} from './interfaces'.
The problem here is i can only import a single file's namespace(even though its the same) hence im creating instance is limited to the import of that specific file namespace.

**Plunker Link** https://plnkr.co/edit/pt90F34KPsGoHDpSUQFD?p=preview

Comment: What about creating a file that exports all your component, then you need to just import this file with a namespace and then you should be able to refer to all components the same way?

Comment: *"Before anyone marks this as duplicate please read below,"* - No, I prefer to judge whether things are duplicates by flipping a coin.

Comment: ok gunter...trying out ur solution will get back...

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer its not able to locate the class even if i do so, should i post a plunker?

Comment: Plunker would be great.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/pt90F34KPsGoHDpSUQFD?p=preview , i need the widget instance to load from the selected string.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `as` with imports like

```
import * as widgets from './lib';
...
this.widgetInstance = new widgets[className]();
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/B3kT529ONBvhJu5yuW6W?p=preview)

I remember this from another answer but I couldn't find it to give some credit :-/

Comment: As always u have been awesome!

Answer (score 4):

You can use eval to create an object from the class name:

```
class SomeClass
{
    x: number;
    y: number;
    constructor() {
        this.x = this.y = 1;
    }

}



function getWidgetObjectFromClassName(className : string) : {}
{
    return eval("new " + className + "();");
}

console.log("%o", getWidgetObjectFromClassName("SomeClass"));
```

Playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20SomeClass%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%09x%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%09y%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%09constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09this.x%20%3D%20this.y%20%3D%201%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20getWidgetObjectFromClassName(className%20%3A%20string)%20%3A%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%09return%20eval(%22new%20%22%20%2B%20className%20%2B%20%22()%3B%22)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(%22%25o%22%2C%20getWidgetObjectFromClassName(%22SomeClass%22))%3B)

Comment: This works perfectly fine, but now for my scenario, when i have my SomeClass on other ts files and even if i import it it cannot find it. Please Check

Comment: Probably you will need to include module or namespace: getWidgetObjectFromClassName("ModuleOrNamespace.SomeClass")

Comment: This is not a clean solution, but definitely works, Why downvote?

Comment: So far, the only solution I've found, thanks! Likely dangerous, though.

Comment: @Raffael could you explain why it is likely dangerous? Is it because ambiguity of the classname might cause the wrong class to be returned?

Comment: Dangerous, due to the possibility that the function gets some javascript injected in place of the class name. Typically the string would be parsed/encoded in some fashion in an attempt to ensure valid javascript is not passed in to be maliciously executed.