# creating instance of a class based on string name of a class

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I am trying to create an instance of a class based on string input parameter.

for ex:

```
class Caller{
  constructor(private factory: IFactory){}
  
  getInstance(productType: string){
    var instance = factory.create(productType);
    console.log(instance);
  }
}



interface IService{}
class ServiceA implements IService{}
class ServiceB implements IService{}

class IFactory{
  create(productType: string): IService;
}

class Factory implements IFactory{
  create(productType: string): IService{
     // I want to return any child service class ServiceA/ServiceB instance here
     // I know I can do conditional instance creation by comparing input string to the type 
     // but don't want to do that
  }
}
```

I have seen and tried many other similar one's provided on SO, but nothing works for me like:
[Dynamically loading a typescript class (reflection for typescript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15338610/dynamically-loading-a-typescript-class-reflection-for-typescript)

OR

[Creating Instance Of Class Based On ClassName : string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38137840/creating-instance-of-class-based-on-classname-string)

Thanks

Comment: "I have seen and tried many other similar one's provided on SO, but nothing works for me."  This makes me suspect that if someone proposes a solution, you will be unhappy with it. Can you elaborate on exactly what doesn't work for you and why?

Comment: @jcalz have updated my question with couple of links

Comment: And why don't they work for you?

Comment: @jcalz giving errors in almost every case

Comment: That sounds like you couldn't figure out how to use the solutions, not that they are the wrong solutions for your problem.  In that case, please edit the question to show your attempts and what errors you are getting.